# Position of element

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

please check plunker 
    https://plnkr.co/edit/rXyZqkPeJyF2GHhbQrDn?p=preview

```
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="firsrChild">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="secondChild">
    a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> a<br/> 
  </div>
  <div class="thirdChild">

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent{
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  overflow : auto;
  border : 1px solid red;
  position : absolute ;
}

.firsrChild{
  position : absolute;
  top :0;
  height : 25%;
  background-color : yellow;
  width : 100%;
  border : 1px solid blue;
}

.secondChild{
  position : relative;
  height : auto;
  width : 100%;
  background-color : gray;
  border : 1px solid green;
  top :25;
}

.thirdChild{
  position:absolute;
  height : 30%;
  width : 100%;
  top : 50%;
  background-color : red;
  border : 1px solid yellow;
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is

1. the firstChild have absolute position with height 25%
2. secondChild have height 'auto' that should start immediate after first child
3. thirdChild have absolute position but if the secondChild's height increases thirdChild should push down automatically.

eg firstChild's height 25%;
   secondChild's height expanded approximately 40%;
   so thirdChild should start top = 65% (25% height of firstChild and 40% height of secondChild)

Comment: Won't affect it, but you might want to fix the typo in the class `firsrChild` - it's the same throughout so as I say, it won't affect it, but it might be a good idea anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to move your DIVs with a simple script like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topSecond = $('.firstChild').height() + $('.firstChild').position().top;
  $('.secondChild').css({top: topSecond});
  console.log(topSecond);
  var topThird = topSecond + $('.secondChild').height();
  $('.thirdChild').css({top: topThird});
  console.log(topThird);
});
```

I update [your plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/shkfgX7YPbHtEpc1LXVY?p=preview)

p.s: I fixed the firstChild typo